# How to expose the Elasticsearch API via Nginx on Ubuntu?

Tags: nginx, elasticsearch

I have Elasticsearch running on an Ubuntu 22.04 VM:

```
sergey@localhost:~$ curl http://localhost:9200/_cat/indices
green open .geoip_databases                HPZPSV-wTIC8QRDJXPbQEg 1 0 42      5 40.7mb 40.7mb
green open .apm-custom-link                xs9iG0bYSeOoAVbwKuFIMA 1 0  0      0   226b   226b
green open .kibana_7.17.9_001              IQkokiYCSMm2JHng6Bo8yg 1 0 41     20  2.3mb  2.3mb
green open .kibana_task_manager_7.17.9_001 b7lptlxqRnuAMrQ0OSe1fg 1 0 17 148089 14.3mb 14.3mb
green open .apm-agent-configuration        jxz881SzS1G9m5SOuGsX9g 1 0  0      0   226b   226b
```

Now I want to configure Nginx so that the same request works via 'elastic.mydomain.com'. What I did:

```
sergey@localhost:~$ cat /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/elasic.mydomain.com
server {
  listen 8080;
  server_name elasic.mydomain.com;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:9200;
  }
}
sergey@localhost:~$ sudo service nginx reload
```

First, I get a timeout when querying http://elastic.mydomain.com, and then ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.

What am I doing wrong?